# May I post a question about a programming dispute?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, self-answer

I have a dispute about a programming issue. Is it acceptable to make a question in SO to attempt to solve it?

The issue in dispute would be.

> Java Synchronization. If a synchronized method is invoked, only the
>   invoking thread has access to the Object instance, any other thread
>   attempting to access that same instance will have to wait.

If making such a question is acceptable. How should I do it?

Should I cite the original statement? Provide a link? Could this be considered as tarnishing the reputation of the cited person if it turns out the cited text is wrong?

Should I just cite the disputed text and ask if it is true? Or do I need to ellaborate or phrase it in a different way?

Should I post also an answer with an explanation of why I think it is wrong accompanied by a small program demonstrating my point?

Comment: Post a  MCVE along that confirms your doubts.

Comment: You can try selfanswering, and if you are wrong your answer will be downvoted and somebody will post another answer explaining why the claim is true.

Comment: This "dispute"--is it with some other human, or with something written in a book? Most disputes are back-and-forths, with arguments and counter-arguments; is that the case here, or do you mean that you simply believe something said or written is wrong?

Comment: Not a book. It is part of a SO answer. That part has already been disputed in comment but the answer poster disagrees. The question is about time execution improvement with threads though, so not the place to further discuss if synchronized methods block access to objects.

Answer (score 11):

You're going to want to do your homework first.

[There's a lot of discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085709/what-does-synchronized-mean) on this subject already, complete with examples, which go a ways to answering your question already.  If one were to see a new question asking about `synchronized`, depending on how it's phrased, I would see it being closed as a duplicate of that.

There's no problem with creating a question to clarify a problem you have, but you really need to do your homework on something like this.  The worst thing that could happen is that you're called out on it and it turns out to be a duplicate, or is poorly researched.

Comment: Good advice. I've found [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14447095/7351954) and [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14447160/7351954) I'll be referencing in this dispute. It may still be useful to ellaborate about how to make such a question when the research turns out empty.

Answer (score 4):

> Should I post also an answer with an explanation of why I think it is wrong accompanied by a small program demonstrating my point?

Regarding an answer I think that's the best way to go, if you're in doubt regarding a concisely asked question.